# Macbook Pro 13 inch (2013 Haswell Retina) - Unable to Install Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, 14.04, macbook

I just tried installing Ubuntu 14.04 on my Macbook Pro (2013 Haswell Retina) laptop and it doesn't work.

I'm using the rEFInd bootloader and I've been able to load the live CD and run Ubuntu without issue.

I'm able to connect to the internet because I'm using an ethernet dongle - the Broadcom wifi drivers weren't recognized by default.

However, after installing Ubuntu from the live CD interface Ubuntu asks to be restarted. The installation appears to have finished because I can see it in the rEFInd menu. I selected Ubuntu and the grub boot loader loads, but Ubuntu boots to a blank screen (it looks like it's running a command line because there is a blinking cursor).

I'm unable to run the recovery mode from Grub because I run into similar problems.

Specs:

Macbook Pro 13 inch Retina (Haswell)

Core I7-4558U processor (Intel Iris 5100)

I'm not sure how to fix this so I'd really appreciate some help.

Thanks.